# Fail to authenticate with pydrive to google drive

Tags: python, macos, python-3.8, pydrive

I am following the instruction to use PyDrive on this documentation [link](https://googleworkspace.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/quickstart.html)
and after running this part

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication.
```

everything seems to work fine, my browser opens and I need to authenticate with my Gmail account. But after accepting the last part the process loads and I get an error message in the browser
[Safari Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFhWL.png)
it's German and it basically says that safari wasn't able to connect to localhost:8080.

In the terminal I get this Traceback:

```
Failed to find "code" in the query parameters of the redirect.
Try command-line authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gepluse/CodeProjects/ComunioBuster/test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()  # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication.
  File "/Users/gepluse/CodeProjects/ComunioBuster/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 115, in _decorated
    code = decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gepluse/CodeProjects/ComunioBuster/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 241, in LocalWebserverAuth
    raise AuthenticationError('No code found in redirect')
pydrive.auth.AuthenticationError: No code found in redirect
```

I also followed this tutorial [link](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-google-drive--api-in-python) and I checked every step I made several times without any success.

In some posts here the firewall was the issue but the firewall on my Mac isn't activated.

I'm running macOS 10.15.7 / Python 3.8.3 / PyDrive 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes according to this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542604/12554227) by Dano. The save and load of `mycreds.txt` helped to solve this issue.

Comment: I am having this issue as well but I'm not able to solve it.  Are you saying you were able to solve it with adding this step: 
```
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    # Authenticate if they're not there
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    # Refresh them if expired
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    # Initialize the saved creds
    gauth.Authorize()
# Save the current credentials to a file
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
```?