# Using Pydrive for automatic uploading

Tags: python, google-oauth, pydrive

I am using `Pydrive` module for uploading files to my google drive. The code which I am using:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()           
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) 

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'hello.txt'})
file1.SetContentString('Hello world project')
file1.Upload()
```

When I run this code, browser opens and I need to click on the google account for sign in. This process repeats everytime I run the code. Is there a way where on running the code, the file uploads automatically? like providing google email account and password in the code.

Comment: checkout the docs, there appears to be LoadCredentials and SaveCredentials functions

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419188/automating-pydrive-verification-process)

To automatically Upload Files to Google Drive via PyDrive module use this code template

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()

# ---Try to load saved client credentials ---#

gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    # Authenticate if they're not there
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    # Refresh them if expired
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    # Initialize the saved creds
    gauth.Authorize()
# Save the current credentials to a file
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

# ------------------------------------------ # 

gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) 

file1 = drive.CreateFile()
file1.SetContentFile('shoe.png')
file1.Upload()
```