# Is there any way to run a python script using the google API / Oauth function without needing to authenticate the account every time the script runs?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Here is a quickpython  script that I wrote to upload a file to Google Drive:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)  

upload_file_list = [#placeholderfilename]
for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '#placeholderdriveID'}]})
    # Read file and set it as the content of this instance.
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload() # Upload the file.
```

This script works, but every time it runs it also opens a window to authenticate the account accessing the drive. My goal for this script is to run it every morning with no input. Is there a way to set up the API so I don't need to manually authenticate the account every time I access google drive? Or does Google not allow that?

Comment: follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention . You will need to figure out how to inject an Access Token to GoogleDrive, or simply throw the library away and call the https endpoints directly.

Comment: or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419188/automating-pydrive-verification-process?rq=1

Comment: The Answer to this question was that I needed to set up a service account through Google's Cloud Console. You'll need to download a JSON file with the account info. Put it in the working directory to allow the script to access it. Here's an article that details how to upload a file with a service account in JavaScript ( https://www.labnol.org/google-api-service-account-220404 ). Obviously the JavaScript Section isn't helpful for writing python scripts, but it will show you the steps to create a service account.

Comment: This is a blog that helped me set up my own script: https://blog.zephyrok.com/google-drive-api-with-service-account-in-python/