# Service Account and PyDrive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, pydrive

I would like to use the Google Drive API to store some backups on it using a cronjob. I just don't understand how I can use PyDrive using a Service Account. When I generate the service account file, and I put it in the directory as my script as `client_secret.json`.

Using this code :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-


from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

def main():

    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

    f = drive.CreateFile({'parent': 'toto'})
    f.SetContentFile('test.drive.py')
    f.Upload()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Result

```
pydrive.settings.InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file Invalid file format.
```

Well ok. Then I look at other posts on SO, and find these two :
[Automate Verification Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555433/pydrive-and-google-drive-automate-verification-process)
The code from the first answer on this question returns this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.drive.py", line 4, in <module>
    from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
```

And then this one :
[Automating pydrive verification process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419188/automating-pydrive-verification-process)
Which just... Doesn't help me much.

Where should I start ? What should I do ? Could someone give me an example with pydrive and Service Authentication just to upload a file ?

EDIT :
After some more research it seems like I needed to install `pycrypto` to fix the import error described above. I don't know why as it is not specified in the error message.

Comment: Have you figured out how to use it ? If you have a code example that you could put as an answer that would be great as I'm currently trying to do the same thing !

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I needed to install `pycrypto` for this to work. Though I stopped spending time on this, so I can't help you any further...

Comment: How did you create your client_secrets.json ?

Comment: @TheWindwaker See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets

Comment: @Depado I just wanted to know how did YOU create it, you might have chosen wrong settings while creating it

Comment: @TheWindwaker I should answer my own question. The only thing I needed for this code to work was to install PyCrypto as specified in my last edit. The problem did not come from the `client_secrets.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research it seems like I needed to install `pycrypto` to fix the import error described above. I don't know why as it is not specified in the error message.